# How to return a list which contains certain element from lists of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a more efficient way to return a list that contains a certain element from a list of lists?

**For example:**

`lists = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']]`

If my input is `C` return the list `['C']` or if my input is `D` return the `list = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']`

**What I've tried:**

```
for lst in lists: 
    for n in range(len(lst)):
        if element == lst[n]:
            print(lst)
```

This is inefficient and I would like to know how to make it more efficient.

Comment: use `for item in lst:` instead of `for n in range(len(lst)):` and `lst[n]`

Comment: You can simplify the inner loop to `if element in lst`, but otherwise no choice but to loop...

Comment: I answered, let me know if that helped! I used a function.

Answer (score 3):

It might help you:

```
lists = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']]
for lst in lists:
    if element in lst:
        print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for lst in lists:
    if element in lst:
        print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `in` operator:

```
def foo(lists, element):
    for l in lists:
        if element in l:
            return l
print(foo([['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']], 'C')) #prints ['C']
print(foo([['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']], 'D')) #prints ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Let me know if that helped!

Summary of answer: I used a function with parameters as the list, and the element. Basically I looped through each list in the list of lists, and checked if the element is in each list. If so, I return that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
lists = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']]

user_input = input("Please enter your input: ")

for item in lists:
    if user_input in item:
        print(item)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your welcome:

```
lists = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C']]
element ='D'
lst = [lst for lst in lists if element in lst]
print(lst)
```